# Highlight the searched words with limited words of String

Tags: php, regex

i want to highlight the keyword searched , i found the solution here but it is showing whole string with matching word highlighted
I want only 10word after and before of the match 
This is what i am using but does not work

```
$text = preg_replace("/^.*?(.{0,1})\b($keyword)\b(.{0,1}).*?$/i", '\1<span class="highlight">\2</span>\3', $text);
echo $text ;
```

Comment: CAn someone resolve the issue please.

Answer (score 0):

Now tested with php. Something like ...

```
<?php
$src = 'twelve eleven ten nine eight seven six five four three two one KEYWORD one two three four five six seven eitht nine ten eleven twelve';
$keyword = "KEYWORD";
$regex = "/(.*?)((\w+\W+){0,10})($keyword\W+)((\w+\W+){0,10})(.*)/i";
$text = preg_replace("$regex", '\1<span class="highlight">\2\4\5</span>\7', $src);
echo $text;
?>
```

... should do it (highlighting the keyword plus 10 words before and after.
Probably there are more compact alternatives...

Sample input:

```
twelve eleven ten nine eight seven six five four three two one KEYWORD one two three four five six seven eitht nine ten eleven twelve
```

... outputs ...

```
twelve eleven <span class="highlight">ten nine eight seven six five four three two one KEYWORD one two three four five six seven eitht nine ten </span>eleven twelve
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not a PHP developer and don't have a PHP environment to test it. If you let me know what's going wrong, I might still be able to help you.

Comment: It is showing then words before and after in yellow with whole text , i want only keyword in yellow and 10 word before and after,